# Calling method cannot see variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this bit of code that basically gets a connection string from a json appsettings file and creates a configuration object to be used by the code to connect to a specific database. This code needs to be called from various methods therfore I am trying to create a method where I dont have to repeat the code but in the calling method the compiler is tell me configuration variable does not exist in the current context, can someone please help, thanks in advance!

```
  private static void GetJSONConnection()
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
            var configuration = builder.Build();
        }

  public static void CreateDB()
        {
 var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLConnection");
}
```

Comment: `configuration` is a local variable of `GetJSONConnection`. Most likely you should just return it from the method.

Comment: You should not use SO as tutorial site : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`configuration` is a local variable, thus you can't access it from different scope (like from `CreateDB()`.

An easy solution would be to turn `configuration` into a field of your class:

```cs
private static IConfiguration _configuration;

private static void GetJSONConnection()
{
     var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
     builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
     _configuration = builder.Build();
}

public static void CreateDB()
{
     var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLConnection");
}
```

Comment: This works well, just need to invoke the method before the creation of the connectionString in the calling method  GetJSONConnection(); Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `configuration` is local, so it can't be accessed from a different method. Try returning it from the method, and calling that method instead:

```
private static Configuration GetJSONConnection()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);
    var configuration = builder.Build();
    return configuration;
}

public static void CreateDB()
{
    var connectionString = GetJSONConnection().GetConnectionString("SQLConnection");
}
```

I'd recommend reading up on scopes and look at some basic intro to C# tutorials online to try to understand this.